# Upload video to facebook from android app using Android Facebook sdk 4.0+

Tags: android, facebook, video, sdk, upload

Hi I want to upload videos from my application (links parse url) for Android to the Facebook page of a user who uses the latest SDK 4.0+ with ShareVideoContent, but no dialogue appears facebook me. With ShareLinkContent working properly, but the video does nothing. Please can someone help me? I have days looking for a solution.

The size of all videos is less than 10 mb

This is my code:

```
                if (model.getThumbnail() != null) {

                    Uri videoFileUri = Uri.parse(model.getThumbnail());
                    ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                            .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
                            .build();
                    ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                            .setVideo(video)
                            .setContentTitle("Video Title")
                            .build();

                    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
                        ShareDialog.show((Activity) context, content);
                        Log.d("share", "video " + videoFileUri + " - " + video);
                    }
                }
```

This is my Log:

> share: video
>   http://files.parsetfss.com/1564fdd0-2ede-4314-9657-3b45e874b278/tfss-f7816d5f-812c-42c9-bd73-8932f794e825-SampleVideo_1080x720_5mb.mp4
>   - com.facebook.share.model.ShareVideo@34a93f5e

Comment: Your use of ShareVideoContent looks fine to me. I would try different video `Uri`s (e.g. local files) and see if that get you in the right direction

Comment: Did you solve the problem?